# Autopublish album in Google+ photos

Tags: google-plus-photos, instagram

Okay, in spite of the hate being heaped on by iPhone elitists, I have installed Instagram on my Android phone and have started playing with it a bit.

**How can I get my Instagram photos to automagically appear in a public album in Google+ Photos?**

Felicia Day, for instance, has [a public Instagram album](https://plus.google.com/photos/110286587261352351537/albums/5627898447762720193).

I can see, on my phone, an Instagram album (which was automatically created by the app), but there is no such album in my Google+ Photos. The options for the phone album do not include a "make public" option, and there's nothing in the Instagram settings. At best, the photos are appearing in the default "Photos from your phone" album.

I know that I can manually share them, either through the website by making a public album and moving/copying them there, or using the Share features on my Android, but I'd rather have something automatic.

Is this possible, or just a pipe dream?

([Cross-posted at *Web Applications*](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/25436/354).)

Comment: "That girl"? That's funny. She mentioned that she's using [instaport.me](https://plus.google.com/110286587261352351537/posts/cWtmjDa1MQm), but all that does right now is offer to let you export your Instagram photos in a zip file. She's obviously not doing it automatically at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/) (If This Than That) and setup a [recipe](https://ifttt.com/recipes/71262) that auto posts from Instagram to a specific Picasa album online. This doesn't require you to leave anything open. Then you can set your Instagram album in Google+ to be public. You will need to follow the directions found [here](http://support.google.com/picasa/answer/1321133/?hl=en).

The only thing I haven't figured out yet is how to share something to my timeline whenever a new post arrives into that album.

Comment: Well yes, that's [what I did](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/36470/354). (Shouldn'ta cross-posted.)

Comment: hehe, sorry, it was and old post and I was searching myself. 8^D Did you ever get your album to auto post to your stream once your photo was uploaded?

Comment: No, but I'm okay with that. I'd rather have a bit more control.

Answer (score 2):

Someone posted a [how-to](http://www.androidcentral.com/sync-your-instagram-photos-google-how) recently to do exactly what you're asking for.

> You'll need a few tools to get started here, and luckily they are
>   available for Windows, Mac, and Linux. This method uses Dropbox and
>   Picasa3 to keep things synced up, and a side benefit is that photos
>   are available from anywhere -- not just the device that took them.
>
> To get started, you need to install the Dropbox client on your home
>   computer. If you already have a Dropbox account, you can use the same
>   login and you'll find that having Dropbox installed on your computer
>   is a good thing anyway. Just visit this link and download the correct
>   version for your computer platform. Install it, and you're done with
>   the first step.
>
> Next, you'll need to install the Picasa3 program from Google. It's a
>   pretty good photo organizer and viewer, but what we're interested in
>   is the way it can sync a folder to your Google+ photos. This is where
>   the magic will happen. Visit this link and download the appropriate
>   version, and install it. Windows and Mac users have it easy, but if
>   you're running Linux you'll need to install Wine 1.3 or higher, and
>   use winetools to install the bits from ie6 to get the account Oauth
>   working. There's plenty of tutorials on the net for this, and if you
>   hit a snag, holler at me.
>
> Got those installed? Good. You're just about finished. The next step
>   is to visit Instadrop and setup the Instagram to Dropbox sync.
>   Instadrop is a web-app, running on Google's appspot engine, and is
>   what makes this all work. You'll link the Instadrop app to both your
>   Instagram account and your Dropbox account, and anytime you post a
>   picture to Instagram it will get copied to a folder named "Instagram
>   photos". All you need to do is link your accounts, and the app does
>   the rest. You can do that here, and if you're the suspicious type, you
>   can inspect the source code on Github and see exactly what's going on.
>
> A couple final steps setting up Picasa and your Google+ album. Open
>   the Picasa program, and click File > Add folder to Picasa. In your
>   Dropbox folder, find the Instagram photo directory (if it's not there,
>   upload a picture to Instagram to create it) in the tree and mark it to
>   "Scan Always" (the blue circular arrow). This means that Picasa will
>   hit that folder each time it scans for new content, and automagically
>   import any pictures it finds. Click the OK button.
>
> Now in the Picasa program, look in the upper right. You'll see a spot
>   to sign-in with your Google account. Do that, and make sure the Sync
>   to Web switch for the Instagram photos folder is set to on. Open your
>   Google+ page, and make sure the Instagram photos album is set up to be
>   shared with the folks you want to share it with, and that's it.
>
> What's happening is that anytime you post a picture to your Instagram
>   stream, the Instadrop web-app pushes it to the Instagram photos folder
>   in your Dropbox. When your computer is on, Picasa uploads it to your
>   Google+ album. Is it perfect? Not by a long shot. But it's a way to
>   get that content merged without waiting for Google to have a public
>   API for content posting and sharing on G+ from third party apps.
>
> Note that these pictures aren't shared to your Google+ stream be
>   default. Until we get some sort of G+ API from Google, that's not
>   going to happen (at least not easily). But if you share your album,
>   people can visit and check them out, and of course you can easily
>   share a photo from the album yourself. Click on it and hit the Share
>   button in the bottom right.

Comment: Ick. I saw that how-to and it's a no-go for me. I really don't want to keep Picasa on all of the time, for one thing. But thanks. If nothing else comes up this looks like my best option.